# Bootstrap 4 li item full width

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

My navigation li items do not use the full space. Why is that? I'm using bootstrap 4.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="navigation__name nav-item" class="col-md-3">Forum</li>
            <li class="col-md-3">Home</li>
            <li class="col-md-2">Registreer</li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><a [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2"><a href="http://www.home.nl">Naar Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>


li
  background #3c3e42
  color white
  padding 0px
```

Example:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Your background color should really be applied to the UL, not the LI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navbar` has padding too. Read the [BS4 docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/).

You should be able to use..

`<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-dark bg-inverse">`

http://codeply.com/go/M6IvbqTa1d